# Read and Replace key-value properties using Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I wanted to replace the keys in my template file (found recursively using find) with the corresponding values. The keys will be loaded from a properties file. See my script below:

Script file Contents:

```
. /home/uname/config/appl.properties
echo ${name_1}
echo ${age_1}
job_1="IT"
echo ${job_1}
for file in $(find /home/uname/config -name "*.txt"); do
  echo $file
  temp_file="/home/uname/temp_file.txt"
  cp -f $file $temp_file
  rm $file
  envsubst < $temp_file > $file
done
```

appl.properties Contents:

```
name_1="theBestName"
age_1="25"
```

template.txt Contents:

```
My name is ${name_1}, my age is ${age_1} and my job is in ${job_1}.
```

I am able to load the key/value pairs (the echo statement displays the key values), but when envsubst writes out the template file, it is not replacing any of the keys with the values. The output I get is:

```
My name is  and my age is and my job is in .
```

Comment: aside: `for file in $(find ...)` falls afoul of BashPitfalls #1 [http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls].

Comment: ...and if your question is how to edit a file through a pipeline in-place, there are lots of questions and answers about that already. (Short form: either write to a temp file and rename, or use `sponge` from `moreutils`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,@PSkocik: To keep it simple, I copied the file into a temp file, but now I face a different issue. See my edit above.

Comment: Editing a question in a way that makes prior answers invalid is frowned on here. Which is to say that that would have been a fine edit before PSkocik answered; now, not so much.

Comment: btw, `envsubst <$temp_file >$file` is absolutely the wrong way to do it -- a file you write to with a redirection gets truncated and rewritten from the beginning, whereas a move operation is atomic. And then there's the lack of quoting...

Comment: ...see http://shellcheck.net/ for automatic checking/detection/explanation re: the lack-of-quoting issue, and similar.

Comment: ...btw, in-place edits like this are a bad idea in general. Consider naming your template files with a suffix -- `.in` or `.tmpl` are proper -- and stripping that suffix for the processed-output forms; that way you don't lose the template itself, and can always rerun the code to regenerate the desired output.

Comment: ok @CharlesDuffy, will keep in mind all your comments in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`envsubst`, as the name implies, requires that its key/value pairs be in environment variables. Mere assignments create shell variables, not environment variables.

The following is an attempt at a best-practices replacement:

```
set -a # turn on auto-export
. appl.properties
set -a # turn off auto-export

while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  tempfile=$(mktemp "$filename.XXXXXX")
  if envsubst <"$filename" >"$tempfile"; then
    mv "$tempfile" "$filename"
  else
    rm -f "$tempfile"
  fi
done < <(find /home/uname/config -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

---

Key points:

- Quotes are important. Try putting spaces in your filenames and seeing how the original behaves if you're not so sure.
- Using `set -a` before sourcing the file ensures that the variables it sets are present in the environment.
- Using `IFS= read -r -d '' filename` to iterate over names from a NUL-delimited source (such as `find -print0`) -- unlike `for filename in $(find ...)` -- ensures that your code correctly handles filenames with spaces, filenames with glob characters in their names, and other unusual cases.
- Using `while read ...; done < <(find ...)` instead of `find ... | while read` avoids the bug documented in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), wherein variables set in the loop do not persist. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on reading streams line-by-line via this method, and/or the [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) page.
- Using `mktemp` to generate temporary filenames prevents symlink attacks -- think of what would happen if someone else with permissions to write to `/home/uname/`, but *without* permissions to write to `/etc`, created a symlink to `/etc/passwd` (or any other file you care about) named `/home/uname/temp_file.txt`. Moreover, using `mktemp` to generate random names means that multiple concurrent instances of the same script won't stomp on the same temporary filename.
- Writing the output of `envsubst` to a temporary file, and then renaming that temporary file to your destination name, ensures that you don't overwrite your output until it's finished being generated. Thus, even if the process is interrupted when partially completed, you have some level of guarantee that the output file will be left in either its original state or fully written (details dependent on your filesystem's configuration and semantics).

Comment: Thank you for a most comprehensive answer, and also the best practices!

Answer (score 0):

`> $file` truncates the file before `envsubst` starts.
Use [sponge(1)](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/sponge/) from moreutils to get around that or write your own sponge that will capture all its input before writing it out.